# Python: Dynamic array classes. Working with negative indices but not sure how to start this.

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-arrays

Using dynamic arrays, I'm trying to modify the **getitem** method to accept negative indexes but right now, it only accepts positive ones.

This is what I have so far:

```
def __getitem__(self, k):
    """Return element at index k."""
    if not 0 <= k < self._n:
        raise IndexError('Invalid index.')
    return self._A[k]
```

I really just don't how to start it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm thinking about incrementing the k value but that seems inefficient. Is there a better way???

Comment: What’s `self._A`? If it supports negative indices then you don’t need that check at the beginning at all.

Comment: Have a look at `divmod`.  And make sure to handle slices received in `k` if necessary.

Comment: self._A is the capacity in memory allocated for the list. This is not the actual size of the list. This will make a new array in memory when the actual size == capacity.

Answer (score 1):

First test if k is within the range positive range from [0,n), if so return the element using k as the index. If k is negative then add k to n. But first check if k is within the range (-n,0], since n+k for -k < -n will result in a negative index. Adding k to n will index k elements from n towards zero.

```
def __getitem__(self, k):
     """Return element at index k."""
     if k >= 0 and k < self._n:
         return self._A[k]
     else k < 0 and self._n+k >= 0:
         return self._A[self._n+k]
     raise IndexError('Invalid index.')
```